# react-native-firebase/admob rewardedAd.load() not working the second time

Tags: react-native, admob, react-native-firebase

rewardedAd.load() does not load ad on the second time.
Everything works fine with the loading, showing, callbacks for the first ad shown, when I then do a rewardedAd.load() again to load another ad, nothing happens. No errors, no callbacks. Then obviously calling rewardedAd.show() rusults in a admob/not-ready error.

This problem occurs in admob/firebase versions 6.2.0 and 6.3.1

```
if(environment == 'development'){
  rewardedAd = RewardedAd.createForAdRequest(TestIds.REWARDED)
}
else if(environment == 'production'){
  rewardedAd = RewardedAd.createForAdRequest(settings.adsUnitIds.ios.real)
}
// --

rewardedAd.onAdEvent((type, error, reward) => {
  console.log('onAdEvent, type:', type, ', error:', error)
  if(type === RewardedAdEventType.LOADED){
    dispatch({ type: 'AD_LOADED' })
  }

  if(type == 'closed'){ // RewardedAdEventType.CLOSED isn't defined (probably bug), so just made it "closed", which works
    console.log('ad closed, rewarded:', rewarded)
    if(rewarded == true){
      if(!doubleReward){
        dispatch(rewardCoins(settings.coins.ad, 'watched-ad'))
      }
      else {
        dispatch(rewardCoins(settings.coins.ad*2, 'watched-ad'))
      }
      rewarded = false
    }
    dispatch({ type: 'AD_CLOSED', rewarded: rewarded })

    if(showEnded) showEnded()

    setTimeout(() => { // Cannot reproduce bug where re-request of ad isn't available so adding this just in case
      console.log('Start ad re-request')
      console.log('Do we have rewardedAd variable? :', rewardedAd)
      rewardedAd.load()
    }, 200)
  }

  if(type === RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD){
    console.log('earned reward!')
    dispatch({ type: 'AD_REWARDED' })
    rewarded = true
  }

  if(type === RewardedAdEventType.ERROR){
    console.info('Some error with ad:', error)
  }
})

rewardedAd.load()
```

Answer (score 2):

How about try this for auto load after shown?

```
rewardedAd.onAdEvent((type, error, reward) => {
  ...
  if (!rewardedAd.loaded) rewardedAd.load()
})
```

Comment: it says that rewardedAd doesn't have property loaded