# React Native AdMob: The requested InterstitialAd has not loaded and could not be shown

Tags: react-native, admob

Hi I am trying to integrate AdMob to React Native App. 
I am trying to show InterstitialAd when user clicks on back button after reading artcles.
Sometimes ad displays on screen but most of the time it showes the error like below:
[image: The requested InterstitialAd has not loaded and could not be shown]

Banner ads are also not displaying.

However if I use Test Ids then both problem disappear.

Comment: I have the same problem .. please  suggest any solution

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60680314/9444013